# Integrating BlackBerry application with Flurry

Tags: java, blackberry, flurry

Has anyone been able to successfully integrate Flurry with a BlackBerry mobile application? I have imported the FlurryAgent.jar into my project, yet when I go to run the application I am given the error "Module 'FlurryAgent' not found."  I have tried the following:

- Preverifying the .jar file
- Adding the .jar file to the build path of a library project (that my main project references)

It is still not working for me after trying the above - I'm getting ready to pull my hair out, there really isn't a helpful guide to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your project properties, go to the *Java Build Path* section, and then the *Order and Export* Tab. Make sure the check box for the Flurry component is checked.

That solved it for me.

Comment: This solved it for me too (I forgot to mark this thread as solved). It was frustrating when I got this to work after having spent about two weeks on the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Flurry was working fine for me in an application I did a year ago. I just added the FlurryAgent.jar file to the build path and then called `FlurryAgent.onEvent(String);`

I was using NetBeans IDE with Blackberry JDE 4.5

Comment: Hm, thanks for your input.  I wonder if it is because I am using any combination of: BlackBerry JDE 5.0 for Eclipse + a potentially newer version of Flurry...

Comment: You said you added the .jar file to the build path of a library project. Did you rebuild that library after you added the flurry jar? Are you using flurry in some classes in that library? If not, try to add the flurry jar directly to the build path of your main project.

Comment: I tried adding FlurryAgent.jar to the build path of my main project (via add external jar in eclipse), and I still receive the same result.

Comment: seems the problem is specific to eclipse, do you know some sample project which link to external jar ?

Answer (score 0):

The supplied jar is already preverified, so that should have no effect. Mugur is right that the flurry jar must be included in the build path of the application project and must be included in the built application.

Comment: Thanks for that info, RRR. I tried adding FlurryAgent.jar to the build path of my main project (via add external jar in eclipse), and I still receive the same result.

Answer (score 0):

We (Localytics) provide our client libraries in source code to make integration with BlackBerry much, much easier.

We compete with Flurry, but you might want to give it a try: http://wiki.localytics.com